# processing.js not loading images for an animation cycle, missing syntax perhaps?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, processing.js, loadimage

My javascript is not throwing me any errors when testing in a browser, and I have the /* @pjs */ directive.

I am trying to render a patch of flowers, each flower in 13 frames, loaded into a PI Images array.

My paths are good, I think I am missing something in the processing.js workflow, though I cannot find it in the online resources like http://processingjs.org –– it all works in processing on my computer.

I have been fiddling with the same issue for days now :(

This is my processing files ::

```
/* @pjs preload="/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_01.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_02.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_03.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_04.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_05.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_06.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_07.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_08.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_09.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_10.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_11.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_12.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_13.png"; */

//3-1, 2017

//building on last build:
//partial display of the life cycle determined in draw function
//see below, three options

//full-screen mode and clearer settings-portion of the code for display added:

////SETTINGS////

int w = 480; //canvas (surface)
int h = 360;

int distance = 36; //density: greater -> further apart
boolean useDistance = true; //set to false for chessboard-style tiling

//::useDistance enabled:://
int wideCount = 6; //disregarded if useDistance = false, but set to fit images to screen
int highCount = 5;

////----////

int w2 = 240; //image (tulip)
int h2 = 180;

int frames = 4; //animation speed that work with images
int framesCount = 13; //sum frames

String imageFilePrefix = "/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_";
String imageFileSuffix = ".png";

Animation[] animations;

void setup() { 

  size(940, 480);

  background(0);
  frameRate(frames);

  //determining amount of flowers

  if (!useDistance) {
      int wideCount = width / w2;
      int highCount = height / h2;

    }

  int count = wideCount * highCount;    

  animations = new Animation[count];

  //positioning

  int index = 0;
  for (int y = 0; y < highCount; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < wideCount; x++) {
      if (useDistance) {
        //x and y offsets left at zero
        animations[index++] = new Animation(imageFilePrefix, framesCount, imageFileSuffix, x * distance, y * distance, 0, 0, 0);
      }
      else {
        animations[index++] = new Animation(imageFilePrefix, framesCount, imageFileSuffix, x * w2, y * h2, 0, 0, 0); 
      }  
  }
  }

}

void draw() { 
  background(0);

  //drawing each flower

  for (Animation anim : animations) {
    //anim.display();
    //anim.display_grow();
    anim.display_live();
    //anim.display_die();
  }
}
```

and my animation class ::

```
/* @pjs preload="/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_01.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_02.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_03.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_04.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_05.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_06.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_07.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_08.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_09.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_10.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_11.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_12.png,/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/tulip_13.png"; */

//3-1, 2017

// Class for animating a sequence of .pngs, GoL images array/part display

class Animation {
  PImage[] images;
  int imageCount;

  //animation specifics
  int imageStartGrow = 0; //identify offset for partial display
  int imageCountGrow = 3; //duration of partial display
  int imageStartLive = 3;
  int imageCountLive = 6;
  int imageStartDie = 10;
  int imageCountDie = 3;

  int frame;

  int xOffset;
  int yOffset;
  float x, y;
  int unit;

  Animation(String imagePrefix, int count, String imageSuffix, 
  int xOffsetTemp, int yOffsetTemp, int xTemp, int yTemp, int tempUnit) {
    imageCount = count;
    images = new PImage[imageCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
      String filename = imagePrefix + String.format("%02d", i + 1) + imageSuffix;
      images[i] = loadImage(filename);
    }

    xOffset = xOffsetTemp;
    yOffset = yOffsetTemp;
    x = xTemp;
    y = yTemp;
    unit = tempUnit;
  }

  void display() {
    frame = (frame+1) % imageCount;
    image(images[frame], xOffset - x, yOffset - y);
  }

  void display_grow() {
    frame = (frame+1) % imageCountGrow;
    image(images[imageStartGrow + frame], xOffset, yOffset);
  }

  void display_live() {
    frame =  (frame+1) % imageCountLive;
    image(images[imageStartLive + frame], xOffset, yOffset); 
  }

  void display_die() {
    frame =  (frame+1) % imageCountDie;
    image(images[frame + imageStartDie], xOffset, yOffset);
  }
}
```

and finally, on my page ::

```
<canvas data-processing-sources="/static/other/processing/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display/Garden_of_Life_images_array_part_display.pde"></canvas>
```

and of course, I am loading in the processing.js script as well

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main/processing-v1.4.8.js">
```

as a side-question, can I keep my .pde files separate in the same directory, or would I need to merge them?

I have tried both with no success: the output on my page when loaded is a blank black field where the canvas should appear. If I try and load processing files without images, they load perfectly?

Suggestions? (Please! ;))

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of your whole project. This can be as simple as loading and displaying a single hard-coded image. Also please link to your code running in a webpage we can visit.

Comment: okay, I'll make sure to add that! (as soon as I can get to it) –– However, I was thinking the issue might just be something in the syntax, specifically related to one of these, in translating from processing to processing.js: loading an image array with PImage[imageCount], the way I use the class Animation to actually accomplish this (in a separate .pde), or the * @pjs */  or something like it when it comes to writing out the js file. (?)

Comment: That's a lot of different possibilities to ask us to debug for you. You really should try to isolate your problem to a single piece of code that isn't working how you expected it to before you ask a question on Stack Overflow. See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I followed your advice, took it apart, and actually got it to work that way. I still need to find what the exact issue is, but I'm just happy it's running now. Lesson learned! Will keep in mind the next time I post –